# Contract Development: How can I run an entire folder of scripts through Brownie?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, brownie, ganache-cli, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my "deploy.py" file, and I was having trouble just deploying that at first, however, I figured that out. Is there a way that I can run every script under a certain folder at the same time. Currently, I run `brownie run scripts\deploy.py` but it only runs deploy.py. Lets say I have another script in the "scripts" folder, and I want to run both at the same time. Is this possible, and if so, what can I run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a script called "all" and have it call the other scripts. This is the easiest solution.

edit:
Okay so you are new to python...

in all.py enter the following

```
from .first_script import the_function
from .second_script import other_function

def main():
    the_function()
    other_function()
```

Then use "brownie run all"

Comment: You are saying. Make a script called all.py, and then create some code that calls all of the other scripts. What a python function that I can use to call these scripts? @CyAaron Nava

Comment: updating my answer